# Strange letter spacing

Tags: html, css, font-face

I have a strange letter spacing only between the "a" and the "p" like the image below. As you can see in the screenshot the string is equal to "appshop" but the view looks like "a ppshop" (same for "download app").

On Internet Explorer it works okay but in all other browsers (Firefox, Chrome and Safari) it does not.

The font is Omnes which can be found at: https://typekit.com/fonts/omnes.

[image]

My @font-face looks like this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Omnes';
src: url('../fonts/OmnesSparv-Regular.eot');
src: url('../fonts/OmnesSparv-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/OmnesSparv-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/OmnesSparv-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: 400;
font-style: normal;
}
```

And nothing wrong in the source code of the element

```
    .header .navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
    color: #818386;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
@media (min-width: 992px)
style.min.css:1
.header.header-transparant .nav-item .nav-link, .header.header-transparant .open {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9) !important;
}
@media (min-width: 992px)
style.min.css:1
.navbar-toggleable-md .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding-right: .5rem;
    padding-left: .5rem;
}
style.min.css:1
.navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
style.min.css:1
.nav-link {
    display: block;
    padding: .5em 1em;
}
style.min.css:1
a, area, button, [role="button"], input, label, select, summary, textarea {
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
}
style.min.css:1
a {
    color: #ec008c;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-decoration-skip: objects;
}
style.min.css:1
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
user agent stylesheet
a:-webkit-any-link {
    color: -webkit-link;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: auto;
}
Inherited from li#menu-item-32.menu-item.menu-item-type-post_type.menu-item-object-page.nav-item
user agent stylesheet
li {
    display: list-item;
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}
Inherited from ul#menu-hoofdmenu.navbar-nav
style.min.css:1
.navbar-nav {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
user agent stylesheet
ul, menu, dir {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}
Inherited from body.post-template-default.single.single-post.postid-44.single-format-standard.logged-in
style.min.css:1
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Omnes",sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #292b2c;
    background-color: #fff;
}
Inherited from html
style.min.css:1
html {
    font-size: 15px;
}
style.min.css:1
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.15;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-overflow-style: scrollbar;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
Pseudo ::before element
style.min.css:1
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
Pseudo ::after element
style.min.css:1
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Source code of the element?

Comment: @Dražen updated with the source code of the element.

Comment: Hmm, try changing font to check if issue is caused by it, browser rendering, or css. Do you use reset.css?

Comment: If I change the font is does not appear. With a clean website it does also appear.

Comment: where is your html?

Comment: @repzero see the first screenshot, just a href.

Comment: is it possible to place the actual codes in your question. It now means that  viewers will have to look at the pic and retype the info. Also we don't know if there are any external stylesheets in your html or what css rules are being applied to parent elements that may affect your target anchor...

Comment: If there are not external links, it is a font thing.